# New Foundations in a Homotopy/Intuitionistic Type Theory form?

Tags: lo.logic, constructive-mathematics, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory, new-foundations

New Foundations is a famously odd set theory suggested by Quine in the 1930s which:

- Features a universal set.
- Disproves the axiom of choice.
- Proves the existence of an infinite set by a trivial corollary of disproving the axiom of choice.
- Is not "Cartesian closed", meaning that the evaluation map $e:A\times B^A \to B$ sometimes doesn't exist.
- Has not yet been convincingly shown to be consistent.

My question is: Has there been any attempt at formulating a theory equiconsistent with NF that's more in the style of Homotopy Type Theory (where propositions are subsingleton types) or Intuitionistic Type Theory (where propositions and types are the same thing)? Type theories in the modern sense are thought to be more friendly to computers.

I've tried Googling this, but the term "type theory" has changed meaning since the 1910s, and the older meaning of the term is still found in NF literature.

Comment: I assume Holmes' [tangled type theories](https://randall-holmes.github.io/Papers/tangled.pdf) are *not* type theories in the sense you're looking for?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I'm thinking of a "propositions as types" approach to NF. Or an [ETCS](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS) approach to NF. In both of these approaches, all the sets behave as if they're disjoint, making operations like $\cap$ meaningless or useless.

Comment: Is the motivation the construction of an NF proof assistant? If so, then I think that task should be approached on its own terms, without necessarily imposing type theory as a hard-and-fast additional requirement.

Comment: No, the objective is purely mathematical - but I can see why you thought that, given that I mentioned being more friendly to computers.

Comment: Relatedly, I came across [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.00506.pdf)  by [Beeson](http://www.michaelbeeson.com/research/papers/pubs.php) (followed by [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.09270.pdf)) in which he studies NF set theory over intuitionistic logic, and in it he writes that he has validated the results in Lean.